# When creating a search box that searches titles and content within a google drive, hitting enter pops open an additional embeds google tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, search

I'm creating an advanced search that searches for a term/word within titles and content of files listed in specific Google Drive folders. The search itself works well, but when I try and create the search box on a Google site, when I hit enter, it will pop open the search in a new tab, but it will also pop open a google site that's just a white screen, atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com. I'm not sure if this is just something you can't get around in Google or if there's something wrong with the code for the search box.

```html
<div class='advSearch'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body {
font-family: 'Nunito';font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
<form>
 <input type="text" id='search' onkeypress="handle(runSearch())" />
 <button onclick='runSearch()' style='padding:5px;font-size:10px'>&#128269</button>
</form>
<script>
    function onkeypress(runSearch()) {
        if(event.key === "Enter"){
          alert("Enter was pressed")
          preventDefault();
</script>
<script>
function runSearch() {
let q = document.getElementById("search").value;
window.open('https://script.google.com/a/macros/LINKHIDDENFORPRIVACYPURPOSES/dev/exec?q='+q);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

No need to test for enter on keypress.

Use the submit event if you must.

But why not have NO script?

Your window open will be blocked by ad blockers but this one won't

(Snippet WILL be blocked at SO but not on your server)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet'>

<form id="searchForm" target="_blank" action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/LINKHIDDENFORPRIVACYPURPOSES/dev/exec">
  <div class='advSearch'>
    <input type="text" id="q" value="" />
    <button style='padding:5px;font-size:10px'>&#128269</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a script version (also blocked at SO but not on your server)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let q = document.getElementById("q").value;
    window.open('https://script.google.com/a/macros/LINKHIDDENFORPRIVACYPURPOSES/dev/exec?q=' + q);
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet'>

<form id="searchForm" target="_blank" action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/LINKHIDDENFORPRIVACYPURPOSES/dev/exec">
  <div class='advSearch'>
    <input type="text" id="q" value="" />
    <button style='padding:5px;font-size:10px'>&#128269</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So, that does prevent that secondary tab from opening, but now, when I run the search, it's just pulling up all of the files in the Drive and not actually searching within the documents.